# Typescript Interface / JSON query types

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a spec / library or standard that allows me to specify an interface for instance:

```
interface Customer {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  createdAt: Date,
  age: number,
}

type CustomerQuery = Query<Customer>
```

Where this would be valid:

```
const customerQuery:CustomerQuery = {
  age: {
    greaterThan: '29'
  }
}
```

This query would be valid because all properties would be optional `?` and `Query` would see the types of the incoming interface and allow `number` to queryable with `greaterThen`, `greaterThenEqual`, `lessThen`, `lessThenEqual`, or a value itself, etc.

Comment: You're looking for some existing thing and not a way to define it?

Comment: We can create the `Query` type to transform the interface, as to the library recommendation, not sure if there is one

Comment: I am looking to see if it is possible with typescript.

Comment: I may not completely understand a question, are not you looking for `type CustomerQuery = Query<Partial<Customer>>`

Comment: No, not that simple. I am looking to dynamically create an interface with logic that decides based on the type what the query allows, for instance only numbers and dates would have `>`, `<`, properties, strings could have regexes possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Replace the `number` type with an interface

```
interface NumberField {
    greaterThan?: number
    greaterOrEqual?: number
    lessThan?: number
    lessOrEqual?: number
}

type Query<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends number ? NumberField | number : T[P]
}
```

## Or, replace `number` and `Date` types with the same interface

```
interface ComparableField<T> {
    greaterThan?: T
    greaterOrEqual?: T
    lessThan?: T
    lessOrEqual?: T
}

type Query<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?:
        T[P] extends number | Date ? ComparableField<T[P]> | T[P]: T[P]
}
```

## Or, replace `number` and `Date` types with distinct interfaces

```
interface NumberField {
    greaterThan?: number
    greaterOrEqual?: number
    lessThan?: number
    lessOrEqual?: number
}

interface DateField {
    before?: Date
    after?: Date
}

type Query<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?:
        T[P] extends number ? NumberField | number :
        T[P] extends Date ? DateField | Date :
        T[P]
}
```

## Read also

- [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types);
- [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

A notice: the `Date` type doesn't exist in JSON.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you.

How would this also conditionally extend `Date`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi I edited to add two solutions with `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a few more special types over @Paleo's answer to make mapping between more types and special Fields a breeze.

The idea is to consider a type of the form `type ConstraintsDict = ((s: number) => NumberField) | ((d: Date) => DateField);` as a dictionary (like you'd write in pure code `const dict = { number: 'NumberField', Date: 'DateField'}`).

Then, provided you have a complete dictionary mapping between types and field definitions, you'd want to get NumberField when giving a number: `type GetFromDict<TDict, Tkey> = TDict extends (arg: Tkey) => infer TValue? TValue: never;` does this. Same analogy as before, it can be thought of in pure code as a `dict[key]` which gives 'NumberField' when key is 'number' and gives undefined - which is `never` in our case - when the key does not exist in the dict.

The complete example:

```
interface NumberField {
  greaterThan?: number;
  greaterOrEqual?: number;
  lessThan?: number;
  lessOrEqual?: number;
}

interface DateField {
  before?: Date;
  after?: Date;
}

// Here you can add whatever mapping between a type and its contraints' fields
type ConstraintsDict = ((s: number) => NumberField) | ((d: Date) => DateField);

type GetFromDict<TDict, Tkey> = TDict extends (arg: Tkey) => infer TValue
  ? TValue
  : never;

type Query<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: GetFromDict<ConstraintsDict, T[P]> | T[P] };

/**
 * The following is equivalent to:
  type QueryStuff = {
    a?: number | NumberField;
    b?: Date | DateField;
    c?: string;
  }
 */
type QueryStuff = Query<{
  a: number;
  b: Date;
  c: string;
}>;
```